# ROC Curve reduces when model is applied to a validation dataset

Tags: roc

I am working on a logistic regression model and will appreciate if anyone can help me on this. I built a logistic regression model on a training data set and got AUC of 0.87 , however when I score the the  validation data set using the model the AUC reduces to 0.62. What might be the cause?. Thank you in advance

Comment: How is this question relevant to programming?

Answer (score 0):

ROC curve assess the fit between the model and the data. If you [overfit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) your training data, you will get an overly optimistic estimate of the performance of the model when you assess it with the training data itself (resubstitution).

This is why you must always test your model on a dataset that was not used to train it. Have a look at cross-validation for a common way to do it.